# div накладывается на другой

Tags: html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть 2 div:

```html
<div style="width: 50%;height: auto;display: inline-block;position: absolute;border-radius: 10px;margin-left: 15%;margin-top: 32%;background-color: black;padding-left: 20px;
padding-top: 10px;margin-right: 20px;color:white">
 <div style="width:102.5%;    border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;margin-left: -20px;margin-bottom: 15px;height:35px;">
 <span style='font-size:20px;color: #777777;margin-left:15px;'><i style="color:#ffc600;margin-right:15px" class="far fa-comment"></i>
 Все комментарии</span></div>
 <div>awdawawd<br>awdawawd<br>awdawawd<br>awdawawd<br>awdawawd<br>awdawawd<br>awdawawd<br>awdawawd<br>awdawawd<br></div>
 </div>
<div style="display: block;background: #ffffff;height: 50px;width: 100%;bottom: 0px;margin-left: 8px;border-top: 1px solid #e0e0e0;position: fixed; z-index:98;padding-top:10px;">
<center><input type="submit" value="Сохранить"></center>
</div>
```

Нижний div fixed накладывается на div absolute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте `margin-bottom` к абсолютному блоку. Или так: `margin: 32% 20px 150px 15%;` :

```css
width: 50%;
height: auto;
display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
border-radius: 10px;
background-color: black;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-top: 10px;
color:white;
margin: 32% 20px 150px 15%;
```

```html
<div style="width: 50%;height: auto;display: inline-block;position: absolute;border-radius: 10px;background-color: black;padding-left: 20px;padding-top: 10px;color:white;margin: 32% 20px 70px 15%;">
  <div style="width:102.5%;    border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;margin-left: -20px;margin-bottom: 15px;height:35px;">
    <span style='font-size:20px;color: #777777;margin-left:15px;'><i style="color:#ffc600;margin-right:15px" class="far fa-comment"></i>
 Все комментарии</span></div>
  <div>awdawawd<br>awdawawd<br>awdawawd<br>awdawawd<br>awdawawd<br>awdawawd<br>awdawawd<br>awdawawd<br>awdawawd<br></div>
</div>
<div style="display: block;background: #ffffff;height: 50px;width: 100%;bottom: 0px;margin-left: 8px;border-top: 1px solid #e0e0e0;position: fixed; z-index:98;padding-top:10px;">
  <center><input type="submit" value="Сохранить"></center>
</div>
```